# SQL Selecting if "active" = true

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application i've been trying to select the data from the table from users that are **ACTIVE**, which is on a column from the database as true or false, however when i try to do this code, it doesn't show any data:

```
  com.CommandText = "SELECT [NumMec], [NomeCompleto] FROM [CORE_USERS] WHERE [Activo] like 'T%'";
```

I've tried a different approach, which was controlling the select by doing a (Data.Activo == "True") in the View. But I don't want this approach, I want to control the data from the database:

```
@{
            if (Model != null)
                   {
                        foreach (var Data in Model)
                        {
                            if (Data.Activo == "True")
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Data.NumMec</td>
                                    <td>@Data.Activo</td>
                                    <td>@Data.NomeCompleto</td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        }
                  }
           }
```

[image: The data I want to be shown (This works with the different approach)]

Comment: What is the type of the ACTIVE column in the schema?

Comment: what is your database? and what's data type of "Activo" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on sql server and datatype of Activo column is bit, then the correct syntax is :

```
SELECT [NumMec], [NomeCompleto] FROM [CORE_USERS] WHERE [Activo] = 1
```

bit = 1 means true

Comment: This is the correct answer, I din't realize "activo" was datatype BIT, thank you.